# xprop: error: No window with name exists

Tags: linux, terminal, x11, window-managers

I have a window that I know has this:

```
WM_NAME property: "user : top – Konsole"
```

If I run `xprop` and select the window with the cursor, the output from `xprop` itself tells me:

```
WM_NAME(COMPOUND_TEXT) = "user : top – Konsole"
```

However, when I try to run the xprop command specifying that same name, this is what I get:

```
user@ThinkpadX200:~$ xprop -name "user : top – Konsole"
xprop: error: No window with name user : top – Konsole exists!
```

Comment: It is probably running into trouble with the "–" character.

Comment: Thank you, Thomas. That is the only thing that seems plausible. I'll see if I figure out what the exact problem is.

Comment: Did you find a satisfactory answer to this? I have a similar problem, but with no special characters, just `Todoist`.